# How to remove Data Quality Services completely?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, data-quality-services

When I setup one of our SQLServer 2012 instances a while back, I didn't realize that I have checked "Data Quality Services" feature. Looking at my installation notes, I find that I didn't end up performing any of the post-install task to install this feature so we didn't end up using this feature.

However, when I run the "Installed SQL Server features discovery report", the report would shows that this feature is configured, even though we don't have any of the DQS databases and any of its objects loaded in the instance.

Can someone tell me how to completely remove this feature so that it doesn't show up anymore in the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Setup Discovery Report? 
As always, your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instruction given by Microsoft in this article.

[Remove Data Quality Server Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/remove-data-quality-server-objects)